# Disabling Horizontal Auto scroll in Qt5

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a question about auto scroll in Qt 5. Right now, qt only support disable auto scroll, which means disable horizontally and vertically auto scroll. What if I only want to disable horizontal AUTO scroll in QTableView?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question isn't very specific; do you mean for a specific widget? A QML component? WebEngine?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using widgets.

**If you do not want horizontal scroll bar :**

Widgets having scroll capabilities are derived from `QAbstractScrollArea`.

`QAbstractScrollArea` has a function `setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy`, which can be used to turn off horizontal scroll bar. You need to set `Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff`.

example:

```
yourScrollableWidget->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
```

**If you want to disable the horizontal scroll bar then try as said below:**

Get the object of horizontal scroll bar. And call `setEnabled`.

```
QScrollBar *hScrollBar = yourScrollableWidget->horizontalScrollBar();
*hScrollBar->setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I think Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff never shows the scroll bar. I want my application to have a horizontal scroll bar if I expand a column inside the main window, but if I click this expanded column, this main window won't shift to the right, which means disable the horizontal auto scroll.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please look into it

Answer (score 0):

You can override void QAbstractItemView::scrollTo. One solution that worked for me is the following:

```
void MyTableView::scrollTo(const QModelIndex &index, ScrollHint hint) {
    int bottomMargin(2);

    if (hint == QAbstractItemView::EnsureVisible &&
        index.row() > indexAt(rect().topLeft()).row() &&
        index.row() < indexAt(rect().bottomLeft()).row() - bottomMargin) {
        return;
    }

    QTableView::scrollTo(index, hint);
}
```

You can play with the value of the bottomMargin in order to get optimal auto-scrolling in vertical direction.